# ASP.net Entity Framework Check if exists in database

Tags: sql, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I have VS2015, entity framework 6.  I have a database with one table (Logins)

```
FirstName, lastName, Birthdate, email, password
```

I also have a textbox(s), button

```
tbEmail tbpass and btnLogin
```

How do I check if the users email in the textbox matches one in the database?

So far I have:

```
 protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            Logins Log = new Logins();

    using (LoginDataEntities lg = new LoginDataEntities())
    {
        string @email = tbUsernameL.Text;
        string @password = tbPassL.Text;

        var logged = from L in lg.Logins
                     where L.Username == @email
                     && L.Pass == @password
                     select L.Username;



        if (logged != null) 
        {
            lblSuccess.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            lblFail.Visible = true;
        }


    }
}
```

However, its not working and always enables the success label.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it once with the following snippet:

```
using (LoginDataEntities lg = new LoginDataEntities())
        {
            string @email = tbUsernameL.Text;
            string @password = tbPassL.Text;

            var logged = lg.Logins
.SingleOrDefault(l=> l.Username == @email && l.Pass == @password);

            if (logged != null) // update
            {
                lblSuccess.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                lblFail.Visible = true;
            }
        }
```

Alternatively, can you also look at the following example again:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/b19d5a/custom-user-login-and-registration-page-in-Asp-Net-mvc3-with-razor-and-entity-framework/

Or you refactorisiers the VS template with Individual User Accounts

[image]

Comment: I am getting an error with SingleorDefault  --  "Error CS1061 LoginDataEntities' does not contain a definition for 'SingleOrDefault' and no extension method 'SingleOrDefault' accepting a first argument of type 'LoginDataEntities' could be found"

Comment: Ops sry, lg.Logins.SingleOrDefault(l=> l.Username == @email && l.Pass == @password);
i misst your entity, i will correct in my snippet..